# Delete row when a table has an FK relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I have 2 tables Document and Project.

DocumentID is an FK in the Project table.

Using sql How can I delete Document Records in the Document table,
and also remove their corresponding records in the Project table.

Thanks

Comment: What's your criteria for selecting the row to be deleted from the Documents table?

Comment: ID in documents table >125 is the criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete 
  from projects 
 where documentsFK = (
                      select documentFK 
                        from documents 
                       where documentsFK > 125
                     );

delete 
  from documents 
 where documentsFK > 125;
```

**EDIT**

```
delete 
  from projects 
 where documentsFK in (
                       select documentFK 
                         from documents 
                        where documentsFK > 125
                      );

delete 
  from documents 
 where documentsFK > 125;
```

Comment: (select documentFK from documents where '...').. this will produce mulitiple rows in my case. so the query doesn't work

Comment: you could use in i think, but i may be wrong, you might have to manipulate the returned data a little to use in as well...

Comment: Not the perfect answer but i used to use this method over "cascade" because of safety and more control over what is being deleted, I also used to save the Ids of the FK in a variable of custom sql server data type.

Answer (score 6):

When creating the foreign key, specify is as a [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx) table constraint.

This constraint means that when a document is deleted, all project rows referencing it as a foreign key will also be deleted.

Comment: @raklos - you can always remove and add a changed constraint.